# How to avoid "Unused lexical argument" for condition-case?

Tags: elisp

Here's a sample of the code that I have:

```cl
(define-error 'unsupported-mode-error "Unsupported mode")
(condition-case e
    (if (eq 'a 'a)
        (message "test")
      (signal 'unsupported-mode-error major-mode))
  (unsupported-mode-error
   (signal (car e) (cdr e)))
  (error
   (message "error")))
```

With `lexical-binding` in the current file, I get `Warning: Unused lexical argument e` warning,
although I'm clearly using `e`. Is this a bug or a misunderstanding on my part? And how could I
avoid this warning?

Comment: Looks like a bug to me.

Comment: Looks like a bug to me too.

Comment: Alright, I'll submit the bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is related to [bug #15103](http://debbugs.gnu.org/15103), as is now fixed in 25.1.

Earlier Emacs versions can do this to silence the warning:

```cl
(setq byte-compile--use-old-handlers nil)
```

Comment: Not all earlier versions, just 24.4, IIRC.